# Unable to restore / remove / update a NuGet package because the mentioned version is no longer available

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

I'm trying to give the [SignalR Sample](https://github.com/SignalR/Samples) a test drive but it seems it references an old version of SignalR which is no longer available. The actual problem is that NuGet cannot remove the unavailable package without first restoring it !!!

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR
Install-Package : Some NuGet packages are missing from the solution. The packages need to be restored in order to build the dependency graph. Restore the packages before performing any operations.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetMissingPackages,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand
```

Then there will be a `Restore` button on the `Package Manager Console` which pressing it will result in the following error:

> An error occurred while trying to restore packages: Unable to find version '2.1.0-pre-131116-b279' of package 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client'

**How can I install a newer version of an addressed package if the current version can not be found?**

I'm using:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015
Version 14.0.24720.00 Update 1
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.6.01038
NuGet Package Manager   3.3.0
```

**[UPDATE]**

When I try to uninstall the troublesome package:

```
PM> Uninstall-Package -Id Microsfot.AspNet.SignalR -RemoveDependencies -Force
Uninstall-Package : Some NuGet packages are missing from the solution. The packages need to be restored in order to build the dependency graph. Restore the packages before performing any operations.
At line:1 char:1
+ Uninstall-Package -Id Microsfot.AspNet.SignalR -RemoveDependencies -F ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Uninstall-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetMissingPackages,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.UninstallPackageCommand
```

Comment: try to `Delete all the folders inside of the packages folder.` and
`Update all packages in Nuget Package Manager.`

Comment: @Webruster I've done that a couple of times, that doesn't help.

Comment: You sure that all the folders were deleted?

Comment: I've deleted the `packages` folder just in case. It doesn't help.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can manually remove the dependency by:

1. Close Visual Studio (not a hard requirement, but helpful)
2. In text editor, remove dependency from all packages.config files
3. Remove package from packages/ directory
4. In text editor, remove all references to package from all .csproj files
5. Start Visual Studio
6. Reinstall package through NuGet

Comment: Thanks but there's no `packages.json`, there's only `packages.config` and it's in XML format.

Comment: Upvoted as it works... but this is insane! Surely there must be an easier path to handling this if a NuGet package is no longer available?

Comment: You can do this in Visual Studio. There is no reason to close it. Just delete the reference, remove the package line from the packages (config or json) file. Then refresh Nuget, and install the version you want.

Comment: @JoeHawkins we don't have any way to force nuget to update packages to the latest?

Comment: @hiule I don't know. haven't been in the .Net game for nearly three years. Your best Google is as good as mine.

Comment: Crazy that this is the only solution!

Answer (score 15):

There's an easier solution, if you know the versions that currently exist in the feed. This solution can fix every package in every project.

- Open packages.config file (if you have more than one project, do this for every packages.config file)
- Update versions to the correct ones (i.e. change the version attribute)
- In the Package Manager Console, type `Update-Package -Reinstall`

Hope it helps

Comment: This did not work for me, Update-Package just spewed "Some NuGet packages are missing from the solution. The packages need to be restored in order to build the dependency gr
aph. Restore the packages before performing any operations.". That's a nice catch-22 they got going there.

Comment: Did you try updating your NuGet.exe version? Try nuget.exe update -Self

Comment: Yea this is much easier than the accepted answer. I did that once I swore to never do it again, alas. Never say never, but this makes it much easier, especially with a solutions with hundreds of projects. +1 (But it re-installs EVERYTHING)

Comment: I agree with @ppumkin. It might take a while, but it does the job

Comment: @ppumkin You don't have to have it reinstall everything.  If you add the -id parameter with the package name then it will just do that one package.

Answer (score 2):

What works for me is:

1. Go to the packages.config file,

2. Find "... id="Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client" version="" targetFramework="net45"..."

3. Change  to an existing version, say "2.2.0".

4. Save.

5. Go to Nuget, and update to the latest.

Answer (score 1):

Mentioned by @ferarias in a comment - if you are using `nuget.exe`, try updating it or downloading the [latest version](https://www.nuget.org/downloads).

For me, upgrading from `v4.4.1` to `v4.6.2` was enough to fix the `Some NuGet packages are missing` error.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I'd restarted visual studio. Then I'd removed nuget package entry from package.config.

After that I was able to restore the dependency.