# NuGet error restoring packages

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015, nuget

Suddenly today I click Rebuild on my sln and get...

Error (~10 similar errors):

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     NuGet Package restore failed for project Core: Unable to find
>   version '4.0.11' of package 'System.Diagnostics.Debug'..          0

[System.Diagnostics.Debug 4.0.11](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Diagnostics.Debug/) exists.

**Nuget version:**  3.3.0.212

Other stuff:

- At PM console:  Install-Package System.Diagnostics.Debug -Version 4.0.11

Error:

> Install-Package : Some NuGet packages are missing from the solution.
>   The packages need to be restored in order to build the dependency 
>   graph. Restore the packages before performing any operations.

- `<RestorePackages>` is not [listed](http://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-restore/migrating-to-automatic-package-restore) in the .sln.  So I don't think this thing is configured the [old way](http://blog.davidebbo.com/2014/01/the-right-way-to-restore-nuget-packages.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happened shortly after running windows update.  I updated NuGet to 3.4 (from 3.3) and the issue resolved itself.

in Visual Studio > Tools > Extensions and Updates > Visual Studio Gallery > Nuget Package Manager > Update

Comment: I'm glad that you have resolved your issue and thanks for sharing the solution here. I suggest you mark your answer which is benefit to other communities who has the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

You need to check you have checked the “Allow NuGet to download missing packages” and “Automatically check for missing packages during build in Visual Studio” options under the VS Tools menu -> Options -> NuGet Packages Manager -> General tab.
[image]

If the options are checked but the problem still exist, you need to uninstall all the installed NuGet and then reinstall them again.

And if uninstall and reinstall could not resolve this issue, you can manually remove the dependency with following steps which refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34147484/unable-to-restore-remove-update-a-nuget-package-because-the-mentioned-versio):

> 1.Close Visual Studio (not a hard requirement, but helpful).
>   2.In text editor, remove dependency from packages.config.
>   3.Remove package from packages/ directory.
>   4.In text editor, remove all references to package from .csproj file.
>   5.Start Visual Studio.
>   6.Reinstall package through NuGet.

Comment: Does current Visual Studio version is the same with the one that used to create this solution?

Comment: This is helpful, in my case the issue was an outdated nuget.